# How to run two CSS animations at the same time?

Tags: css, animation, sass, css-animations

I would like to execute two aniamtion, without stopping the first.

I'll show you it will be easier. Here is my code :

```
animation: hover  7s, shake .2s 3s infinite;
```

I have two animations called **hover** and **shake**. The shake one should be executed after 3s so during the first one **hover** because this one has a time set of 7s.

The goal of it is to have at the end a circle getting smaller and shaking at the same time.

But what it does it's when **shake** starts it stops hover even thaugt **hover** should have 4s left.

Any idea to solve that issue? I tried to make all animation at once, but it didn't work correctly.

Am i obliged to make only one animation instead of two  ?

Here is the code of animations :

```
@keyframes shake {
  10%, 90% {
    transform: translate3d(-1px, 0, 0);
  }

  20%, 80% {
    transform: translate3d(1px, 0, 0);
  }

  30%, 50%, 70% {
    transform: translate3d(-3px, 0, 0);
  }

  40%, 60% {
    transform: translate3d(3px, 0, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes hover {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  30% {
    transform: scale(1.3);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(0.3);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide full code? With HTML, use code snippet here or Codepen or JSFiddle

Comment: https://codepen.io/byflo-io/pen/GRpLxGQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the second style rule hides the first because they are both acting on the `transform` property.

Wrap your element into a `div` and give the parent an animation ("hover") and the child another one ("shake"). Note that you have set a `3s` delay to the "shake" animation.

```css
.hover {
  animation: hover 7s infinite running;
}

.cursor {
  animation: shake .2s 3s infinite running;
  &:after {
    opacity: 1;
  } 
}

@keyframes shake {
  10%, 90% {
    transform: translate3d(-1px, 0, 0);
  }

  20%, 80% {
    transform: translate3d(1px, 0, 0);
  }

  30%, 50%, 70% {
    transform: translate3d(-3px, 0, 0);
  }

  40%, 60% {
    transform: translate3d(3px, 0, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes hover {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  30% {
    transform: scale(1.3);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(0.3);
  }
}

.parent {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0; 
  top:0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.cursor {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0; 
  top:0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid #293133;
    &:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    opacity: .5;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="parent hover">
  <div class="cursor"></div>
</div>
```

Here's a working [Codepen](https://codepen.io/alezuc/pen/mdegxax)

Comment: Do you have any idea on how to start the shaking event progressively ? Like slow at first and more the shape get smaller more the shake get faster  ? I tried with the codepen you gave me with cubic-bezier and some other stuff but I didn't make natural at all.

Comment: @crg I guess you have to move to JS if you want to achieve complex animations